# Array.prototype.forEach won't return value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this little snippet:

```
let result = ['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach((element) => element);
console.log(result); // undefined
```

The "problem" is that `forEach` seems to return no value back.

**EDIT**

`.filter` or `.map` for instance return values as expected. 
`.forEach` is different. Why?

My goal is to transform the elements of my array to upper case.

Comment: `forEach()` always return `undefined`. What you wants to achieve?

Comment: forEach doesn't return a value. [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I want to turn my array to upcase. `forEach` seemed the most intuitive way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable.

`forEach()` does not return anything. You can use `map()` instead:

```js
let result = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map((element) => element.toUpperCase());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this the case

`forEach` is designed to iterate over an array. It isn't supposed to do anything else.

> and what can be done about it?

It *looks* like your code is trying to clone the array, so you can use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

```js
let result = ['a', 'b', 'c'].concat();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: easiest way to clone an array is `slice()`.

Comment: "forEach is designed to iterate over an array. It isn't supposed to do anything else.". OK. Why?

Comment: same reason that `for loop`doesn't return anything.. only iterates over element and execute the code written inside loop body

Comment: @kstratis — Why should it do anything else? It's a for loop.

Comment: @Quentin Why not..? `filter` returns each element. So does `map`. Why `forEach` differs?

Comment: Basically, @kstratis, the clue is in the name.